# How to append list of dictionary in python?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, append

I have to update the JSON by appending another list named "Stage3" under "Stage2" in python.

Initially, the JSON format is:

```
"Stage1":{
   "Stage2":[
     {
        ...
     }
  ]
}
```

After adding "Stage3".How I want is:
**Expected JSON Format:**

```
"Stage1":{
   "Stage2":[
     {
        ...
      "Stage3":[
         {
             ...
         },
          {
             ...
          }
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

**Python**

```
Stage1 = {}
Stage1['Stage2'] = []
Stage3 = [#<Where i'm having some dicitionary value>#]
```

How to append "Stage3" data inside this JSON?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Currently `Stage2` is a list, so you can't append items with keys there. unless you want to add it to, say, the first element in that list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import json

Stage1 = {}
Stage1['Stage2'] = [{}]
Stage3 = [{'a': 1}, {'b': 2}]
Stage1['Stage2'][0]['Stage3'] = Stage3

res = {'Stage1': Stage1}
print(json.dumps(res))
```

**Output:**

```
{
  "Stage1": {
    "Stage2": [
      {
        "Stage3": [
          {
            "a": 1
          },
          {
            "b": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
mydict['Stage1']['Stage2'].append({"Stage3":"valueof3"})
```

where mydict have assigned dictionary value.

Check this:
https://repl.it/repls/CourteousGreenDownloads